# For a given group $(G,+)$, $+$ the usual addition and $G$ a set where every finite subset has a maximum then every subgroup of $G$ is infinite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

> I want to prove that given $(G,+)$ a group whith $+$ the usual addition and $G$ a group such that every finite subset has a well defined maximum then there is not any finite subsets in $G$

My proof goes the following way:

Lets suppose that there is $S$ a subgroup of $G$ such that $\#S=n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then, by taking $m:=max(S)$ we get that $m+m \notin S$ therefore $S$ isn't a subgroup and we get to an absurd.

This way we are prooving that for every subgroup $S$, $\#S=\infty$

This can be applyed for say for instance $(Q, +)$

Being this such an abstract proof I'd like someone to check it and let me know wether it's correct. In that case I'd be interested to know if the conditions here could be weakened somehow.

Comment: You need some more structure than just a group to talk about things like maximum elements of a group. In addition, it is not clear what you mean by the "usual addition."

Comment: @NoahSolomon The exact problem I had to solve was the one for $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ so with usual addition I mean the adition in that group. With this post I was trying to generalize this example.

Comment: When you say "finite subsets" do you mean "finite subgroup"? Because of course there are always finite subsets.

Comment: @Nick. I mean finite subset. Refearing again to the example with $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ the proof goes like this. Suppose there is a finite subgroup $S$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then in that subgroup is formed by a finite subset of elements of $\mathbb{Q}$. Now taking the maximum of that subset we see that $m+m$ is not in $S$.

Comment: As @NoahSolomon has also said: in general it does not make sense to talk about maximal elements of an arbitrary group. Not every group has an ordering like ${\mathbb{Q}}$ as in your example. I'd also agree that it's not clear what you mean by usual addition: we usually use $+$ for abelian groups but other than that there's not a whole lot more we can deduce about this $+$ you mention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As many commenters have pointed out, your question, as written, doesn't make much sense. However it's easy to guess what kind of question you wanted to ask, and your intuition and proof will basically work in this new setting.

First, the repaired question:

> Given an (abelian) [linearly ordered group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_ordered_group) $(G,\leq)$, must every nontrivial subgroup be infinite?
>
> Here an (abelian) group $(G,+,-,0)$ is called "linearly ordered" if it comes equipped with a [linear order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) $\leq$ which is *compatible with addition* in the sense that $a \leq b$ implies $c+a \leq c+b$.

Originally you ask about groups with an ordering so that "every finite subset has a maximum". This condition is exactly the condition that $\leq$ be a linear order, so this really is a direct rephrasing of your question!
Moreover, the proof you attempt to give is only making use of the order and group structure, plus implicitly the fact that they're "compatible" in the sense outlined above. So it should go through perfectly well in this setting! There's a few tweaks I had to make, but you had the exact right idea!

Indeed, let $S$ be a finite subset of $G$ containing a nonzero element. Then $S$ *cannot* be a subgroup. Indeed, let $s^*$ be the maximal nonzero element of $S$. If $0 \leq s^*$, then by compatibility we see $s^* + 0 \leq s^* + s^*$ so that $s^* + s^*$ cannot be in $S$, as it is larger than the maximal element. If instead $s^* \leq 0$, then $-s^* \geq 0$ cannot be in $S$, as again it is larger than the maximal element. Either way, $S$ is not a subgroup, and we are done.

---

Now, briefly, why did I put "abelian" in parentheses above? I wanted to stick to your notation for $G$, which was additive, and culturally that usually means that $G$ should be abelian. But notice that we didn't actually *use* the abelian assumption anywhere! In the nonabelian setting, we usually only require the compatibility condition to be true when we multiply on the left. In this case $G$ is called *left orderable*, and the same proof shows that left orderable groups cannot have finite subgroups!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: For completeness, you should also explain why $s^*+s^*$ cannot be in $S$: If $s^*+s^*\in S$ then $s^* + s^* \le s^*$ and adding $-s^*$ on both sides we get $s^* \le0$. This together with the assumption that $0\le s^*$ implies that $s^*=0$ (by the axioms of an order), a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I'm new to working with abstract ideas so it's hard for me to express my thoughts rigurously. However you pretty much said all I wanted to ask in a rigurous way so thanks for that too. Now people can understand better what i meant with the question